# Data table in kivy

Tags: python-3.x, datatable, visual-studio-code, kivy, kivy-language

I have created application in kivy using kivymd , when I used its data_table code I couldn't select multi rows to delete them one time, I tried to create a list and append each selected_id in this list but it returns an empty list.

this is the function which returns a selected_id :

```
def select_row(self, checkbox, checked, **kwargs):
    if not self.is_all_checked:
        for index, cell in enumerate(self.children):
            if isinstance(cell, ItemCheckbox) and checked:
                if cell.id != checkbox.id:
                    self.selected_id = checkbox.id
                    cell.active = False

    elif self.is_all_checked and not checked:
        self.select_all(False)
    if not checked:
        self.selected_id = ""
```

All what I need is to make a list of rows with checkboxes that allow to be check many of them at once to let user delete it! Could you help me do this?

Comment: How many checkbox in a row?

Comment: Each row has one checkbox @ikolim